# Java football team map that references List of Team objects

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm new to Java and currently stuck on an assignment question.

I need to create a method for the LeagueAdmin class called addTeam(), which takes two arguments and returns no value. I'm given the header: public void addTeam(String division, Team team)

The method should check to see if a list for that division already exists in the teams map.

If the list exists, then the new Team should be added to the existing list of teams for that division.

If the list does not exist, then a new empty list of Team should be created and the new Team should be added to it, then a new key-value pair should be created in teams with division as the key and the new list as the value.

My code so far is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LeagueAdmin
{
    public Map<String, List<Team>> teams;
    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class LeagueAdmin
    */
    public LeagueAdmin()
    {
        this.teams = new HashMap<String, List<Team>>();
    }
}
```

I have separate class as follows:

```
public class Team
{  
    private String name;
    private String division;
    private int won;
    private int drew;
    private int lost;
    // no need to record points as = 3*won + drew   


    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Team
    */
    public Team(String aName, String aDivision)
    {
        name = aName;
        division = aDivision;
        // no need to set won, drew and lost to 0
    }
}
```

If anyone can give me some pointers that would be great,

Thanks, Kat

Comment: Hi Kitkat, please tell us what specific problem as you finding in doing this? We can't do your assignment for you but we can help with a problem you might get on your way.

Comment: Hi, I understand Maps and Lists individually, I just can't seem to get the variable teams to reference a Map that's values are a List of Team objects. When I try to use methods such as add(), contains(), put() etc, none of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, a couple of suggestions.

- always declare local variables and fields as `final` when possible
- always format your code. Seems superfluous but it's something I don't see done often
- initialize `final` fields *in-line*, not inside the constructor, if possible
- don't expose fields, which are part of implementation details

---

Edit: being that maybe you need a simplified version, I'll also add that, **but keep reading all my answer, it's fun!**

Follow the comments inside the code to understand the flow.

```
public class LeagueAdmin {
    private final Map<String, List<Team>> teams = new HashMap<String, List<Team>>();

    public void addTeam(final String division, final Team team) {
        // We retrieve the team list, if any
        List<Team> list = map.get(division);

        // We check if the list was already there, or we have to create a new one
        if (list == null) {
           // The list is null, we need to insert a new one!
           list = new ArrayList<>();
           map.put(division, list);
        }

        // We add the team to the list
        list.add(team);
    }
}
```

---

Now, for a more "new" and simplified version, **which does the exact same thing as the one above**, the implementation would be

```
public class LeagueAdmin {
    private final Map<String, List<Team>> teams = new HashMap<String, List<Team>>();

    public void addTeam(final String division, final Team team) {
       teams.computeIfAbsent(division, __ -> new ArrayList<>()).add(team);
    }
}
```

Since Java 8, the `Map` interface exposes a new method

```
computeIfAbsent(Key, Function)
```

What this does is

1. try to get the value associated with the inputted key
2. if no value found, use the Function argument to associate a new one
3. return the associated value

Also, you'll ask yourself what `__ ->` is.
Well, `__` is just a valid variable name, used to say *"hey, I don't need that"*
The `->` (arrow) is part of a lambda expression, which is basically an *in-line* function

Comment: As a homework assignment, I suspect the instructor wants the student to practice manually examining keys and values rather than the shortcut of `computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by LppEdd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54972218/642706) suggesting `computeIfAbsent` is correct, but perhaps not what your course instructor is looking for. She/he probably wants you to more coding than that, as we did do in real work before that new method was added recently.

The old-fashioned of the `addTeam(String division, Team team)` method you need to add to `LeagueAdmin` would ask the map if it has a key for the division string. If no such key, add one, and put as its value a new empty `List` of teams to which you have added the team in question. If there is such a key, retrieve its value, a `List`, and then add the team in question to that list.

As a homework assignment, to do the learning you need to struggle with this a bit rather than copy some existing code. **Study the JavaDoc** for the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) and [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interfaces. Follow my prose above as pseudo-code to walk you through the logic. Be sure you understand the ideas behind each class, especially the [key-value pairing of a map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) (also known as a *dictionary* or an *associative array*). Draw a diagram on paper, imagining each step I outlined above.

So a league object holds a `Map` object. The map holds a collection of keys, each key being a division name (a `String` in your situation, more likely a `Division` class in real work). Being a key in a map means each division name will lead you to a `List` object, a collection of teams. A `List` keeps items in the order in which they are added. A `Set` would like work just as well here, by the way.

Note in this diagram how one of the `List` objects is empty, meaning it has not yet had any teams assigned. An empty list is *not* nothing; an empty list is something. The empty list is still a valid object, just like a fruit basket without any fruit in it is still a basket. If no list, empty or otherwise, has yet to be assigned to a key in a map, the key points to `null` where `null` really does mean “nothing at all”. We see in this diagram that the “division-z” key in the map has not yet been assigned any `List` object at all, so it points to nothing, `null`.

[image: diagram of a "League" object holding a map of division (the key) to list of teams (the value)]

Comment: Wow that is amazing, thank you :) I just need to figure out how to get the map to hold a List of objects as its value now, I think I am getting somewhere now!

Comment: @KitKat Good. If you are using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as IntelliJ/NetBeans/Eclipse, use the debugger as you step through your code to look into the content of all these objects. Or, call `toString` on the objects to see their contents as you add items.